# Why seeding a class in Database is not processed by Model mutators?(Am I missing something)

Tags: laravel

I made a mutator in Laravel model & make a seeder for that table.

```
DB::table('members')->insert([
        'name'=> Str::ucfirst(Str::random(5)),
        'title'=> Str::ucfirst(Str::random(5)),
        'address'=> Str::random(7). ', '. Str::random(3). ', AB-'. rand(599999, 800000),
        'mob_no'=> rand(1000000000, 9999999999),
    ]);
```

Now my seeder data is not processed by my model mutator. Am I missing something?(I'm just learning)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using DB facade to insert to database. In order to benefit from eloquent tools like mutator, you should use instances of Model class. So, create a model for member and then create your record like below:

For creating a model run below command:

```
php artisan make:model Member
```

For creating new record in laravel 8 use below code:

```
App\Models\Member::create([
    'name'=> Str::ucfirst(Str::random(5)),
    'title'=> Str::ucfirst(Str::random(5)),
    'address'=> Str::random(7). ', '. Str::random(3). ', AB-'. rand(599999, 800000),
    'mob_no'=> rand(1000000000, 9999999999),
])
```